# Add composer client library to PHP container

Tags: php, composer-php, dockerfile, guzzle

I'm using a *php:7.2-apache* container to serve `/var/www/html`

How do I make a new image with a composer client library, e.g. http://docs.guzzlephp.org?

Comment: You build the project locally and then `COPY` the files into the container image. You do not need composer to actually exist or run inside the container.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, you do not need Docker to install a package